Datasync hanging when nullable date is NULL
I'm having trouble with nullable dates.  At first my model included this field:
public DateTime CompletedDateTime { get; set; }

When I changed it to...
public DateTime? CompletedDateTime { get; set; }

...and did a migration, everything seemed to work okay at first.  This was only because field CompletedDateTime had a date in it.  When I had a record that had a NULL in that field, any PUSH or PULL operations freeze up and the log in Azure Portal is very vague and simply says there's a 400 Bad Request because of a malformed request.  It can happen if I set the NULL in my local offline table (then try a pushitemsasync) OR in Azure (then a pullitemsasync).
I did notice that EFFrameworkCore is generating a "datetime2(7) NULL" from a DateTime? in C#.  I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the issue.
I'm using .NET 8, MAUI version 8.0.60, Datasync client 6.1.0 and EF Framework Core 8.0.1

I changed the datetime2(7) to datetime and it still does the same thing.

Aside... datetime (Transact-SQL) Avoid using datetime for new work. Instead, use the time, date, datetime2, and datetimeoffset data types. The datetime data type is a legacy left over from when SQL Server was Sybase and will cause you difficulties at some point due to its 1/300th second imprecision.

You mentioned "date" a few times in your question. Do you need the time component of DateTime, or should you be using DateOnly instead?

Sorry, I tend to use those terms interchangeably.  But in this case, I do want to keep the time component as well.  Regarding your 1st comment, thanks for the explanation of how the types differ.  I just can't get past this issue.  It seems like a datasync bug but I can't be sure.
